# Saving bitmap change some colors?

Tags: java, colors, bitmap, pixel

Today I was working on a game in Java, a classic old MUD RPG, and think that was a good idea to create the map with Paint and saving it in bitmap.

The idea is that, I read the image pixel by pixel and based on the color, I load the properties of the cell.

I had no problem to reading it, but I find a strage thing. Some colors change their RGB value, by a little, and then the values that I expected for a particular type of cell is not matched anymore.

In the first place I thought it was my mistake, some errors in the code but opening paint again just give me the answer, which is that some colors (not just some pixel) are changed.

By changing the format from BMP to DIB it seems to work fine. But why saving a bitmap in bmp format change the colors?

This is how I read the map:

```
BufferedImage mapImg = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        int pixel = mapImg.getRGB(y, x);
        int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
    }
}
```

And works fine.

Comment: Please edit your question in include code showing how you load the image and read the pixels, otherwise we can only guess. Also try opening the bmp file in other paint software and check if it shows different colours when using the eyedropper tool, if it does, then the issue is your paint program and how it saves files rather than code.

Comment: @sorifiend done.

Comment: I am not sure if this is your issue `int pixel = mapImg.getRGB(y, x);` but the x and y in `getRGB` should be the opposite way around `int pixel = mapImg.getRGB(x, y);` Does fixing that solve your issue?

Comment: @sorifiend Nope, it is intended

Comment: I can't see any obvious issues in your code, were you able to verify that the correct colors show up in other paint software after creating it the very first time? If not then you will need to use better paint software (gimp, paint dot net etc). Otherwise the only other thing I can think of is that you are not taking the alpha component into account if you are recreating the pixels, for example `int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;`